# How can I apply background color on 30% width in the navbar using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I just wanted to know how to apply on 30% width of background in navbar using Bootstrap.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="background-color: #fff;width:648px !important;" id="navcolor">

  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          
          <a href="#">
              <img src="./Images/Exitimg.png" alt="Exit png">
          </a>
    

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="#"><a href="#"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">
                      <img src="./Images/searchicon.png" alt="Search image">
                  </a></li>
          </ul>
          
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reach</a></li>

          </ul>
          </li>
          </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically how to create a [minimally, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Although you've provided some html, it is not valid (you've got several tags that are not closed, and some closing tags without opening tags).  You also haven't told us which version of Bootstrap.  Best to create a snippet with the exact Bootstrap version CDN links that you're using in your project.

Comment: Your markup is a bit of a mess. You have an anchor inside a button (or a button with no closing tag), and you have several extra closing tags. I suggest using a good editor or an HTML validator. Even proper formatting (indentation) would make these things more apparent.